# java.lang.NumberFormatException for input 1e49643

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am getting following error while executing `Integer.parseInt("1e49643", Character.MAX_RADIX)`.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1e49643".

Can someone tell me whats wrong with input 1e49643 ?

Thanks
Ashraf

Comment: The result would have been `3030455091`, which is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is why you get an exception.

Comment: Do you know the value of `Character.MAX_RADIX`? Note: it's not 16.

Answer (score 0):

1e49643 is a huge number. Integer cannot hold such value.
`Long.parseLong("1e49643", Character.MAX_RADIX);` should work fine.